# Postman post doesn't send any data

Tags: php, post, postman

I'm testing an api using Postman but it doesnt send any data.

When I create a test using php function it works fine.

the api php

```
$json_str = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json_str, false);
```

the test php

```
$obj->CompanyCode= "39170";
$obj->CustomerNumber= "1800001";
$options = array(
 'http' => array(
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'content' => json_encode( $obj ),
'header'=>array(
               "Content-Type: application/json", 
               "Accept: application/json")
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( "https://www.url.com/inquiry/", false, $context );
```

the postman

[postman header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdXqj.png)

[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15LD3.png)

Comment: What response code do you get on Postman?

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'Accept' header on Postman as well?

Comment: i got status 200 ok
accept header tried and didnt work

Comment: i tried to change from post to put and it works somehow. but i need post and not put though.